# Call super without "super" keyword

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-runtime

I want' to implement "Fix and continue functionality" that was in Xcode 3.

**CONTEXT**:

The main idea is:
  When I need to "Fix something fast", I'm not re-compiling, project. I'm compiling small `Attacker class` with 'updated' method implementation, loading it into memory and replacing VictimClass's method which have `incorrect` implementation in runtime.
I think that this method will work faster that full project recompilation.

When i'm done with fixes i'm just copying source of `Attacker class` method to `Victim class`.

**PROBLEM**

At the moment, I don't know how correctly call `[super ...]` in Attacker class.

For example, i have VictimClass

```
@interface VictimClass : UIView @end
@implementation VictimClass
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawRect:rect];
}
@end


@interface AttackerClass : NSObject @end
@implementation AttackerClass 
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawRect:rect];
  [self setupPrettyBackground];
}
@end
....

// EXCHANGE IMPLEMENTATIONS
Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([AttackerClass class], @selector(drawRect:));
const char * types = method_getTypeEncoding(m);
IMP attackerImp = method_getImplementation(m);

class_replaceMethod([VictimClass class], @selector(drawRect:), attackerImp, types);


// Invoking drawRect on Victim
VictimClass * view = /* */;
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

At this point , when `drawRect:` method will be called, this will lead to exception, since `drawRect:` will be called on NSObject class, but not on UIView class

So, my question is, how correctly call `[super drawRect:]` in AttackerClass, to have possibility to correctly exchange implementation in runtime?

Main idea is to provide a way to correctly replace any method in Victim class by Attacker's class method. Generally, you don't know, superclass of `Victim class`.

**UPDATE**: Replacing implementation code added.

Comment: still don't understand, what is Runtime replace method.

Comment: Why do you change the superclass of AttackerClass from NSObject to UIView?

Comment: he doesn't... he just has 2 separated classes

Comment: i love how you use *attacker class* and *victim class* in your question.. very nice analogy to simplify a relatively complex scenario

Comment: do you know how to do the above without falling into a recursive  call of super? see the update to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258071/how-to-override-swizzle-a-method-of-a-private-class-in-runtime-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to

1. get the receivers class (e.g. with `object_getClass(rcv)`)
2. then get the super class of it (with `class_getSuperclass(class)`)
3. then get the implementation of it (with `class_getMethodImplementation(superclass, sel)`)
4. then call the imp.

done

Stop at any step if you got nil or NULL.

Oh, and all this seems silly. But I assume that the question just lacks of context to see the motivation for such a hack.

**[Update]**

An explanation for future readers:

The `super` keyword is resolved at compile time. Therefore it does not the intended thing when changing methods at runtime. A method which is intended to be injected in some object (and its class hierarchy) at runtime has to do super calls via runtime as outlined above.

Comment: Hm... I'll try to do this. And tell you result. this is possibly the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, man, by using this behaviour, you actually can emulate "super" call

Comment: See also [Mike Ash's Friday Q&A on the topic](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-19-creating-classes-at-runtime-for-fun-and-profit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the runtime changes you're making involve modifying the superclass, you'll have to do something like this:

```
@implementation AttackerClass 
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(drawRect:)] )
    {
        [super drawRect:rect];
    }
    [self setupPrettyBackground];
}
@end
```

This will check if the superclass "knows about" `drawRect:`, and doesn't call it in the case that `super` has no `drawRect:` selector.

Hence, when the superclass is `NSObject` the `drawRect:` message will not be sent. When you change it to `UIView` at runtime (whatever your reason for that is), the message can safely be sent.

Comment: you're right... but it's a true fact that when you write your code you already know that your superclass hasn't got that method... no need to call it and no need to check...

Comment: @meronix agreed, but he implied that he is changing the superclass at runtime and doesn't want to send the `drawRect:` message until the superclass has been set.

Comment: I'm still need to call that super... method implementation. Your way is just to skip calling super. But i need to call it same way, like it was before method replacement.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You cannot send a message to a superclass that doesn't respond to said message and expect it to work. The only way to avoid an exception at runtime is **not** send the message to the superclass in the first place. If you're replacing a method instead of replacing the superclass, this is still safe and the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use objc_msgSendSuper.  Your method **-[AttackerClass drawRect:]** will have the following implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  struct objc_super superTarget;
  superTarget.receiver = self;
  superTarget.class = object_getClass(self);
  objc_msgSendSuper(&superTarget, @selector(drawRect:), rect);
  [self setupPrettyBackground];
}
```

Comment: btw i used your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26272294/766570).. worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score -2):

but why do you need to call draw rect method for superclass NSObject, when NSObject hasn't got that method? just don't do it... call it just in VictimClass drawrect