# how to override/swizzle a method of a private class in runtime objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios, objective-c-runtime

To give a bit of context of why I'm asking this: basically I would like to change the location of the `myLocationButton` of the google map on iOS. So I first fetch the actual button like so:

```
@implementation GMSMapView (UIChanges)

- (UIButton *)myLocationButton
{
    UIButton *myLocationButton;
    for (myLocationButton in [settingView subviews])
    {
        if ([myLocationButton isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            break;
    }
    return myLocationButton;
}
```

Then I try to change it's position in the screen using NSLayoutConstraints (directly changing values of the `frame` property of the button does nothing with google maps SDK 1.8+):

```
UIButton *myLocationButton = [mapView_ myLocationButton];
[myLocationButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[myLocationButton constraintRightEqualTo:[myLocationButton superview] constant:0];
[myLocationButton constraintTopEqualTo:[myLocationButton superview] constant:50];
```

where `constraintRightEqualTo` is defined in a category as:

```
- (void)constraintRightEqualTo:(UIView *)toView constant:(CGFloat)constant
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight

                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:toView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                         multiplier:1 constant:constant];

    [toView addConstraint:cn];
}
```

so far so good? ok.

Now this works just fine in iOS8.. however when I run this in iOS 7 it crashes with this famous error:

> -[TPMURequestStatusNotificationManager
>   makeActionButtonResponsive]:810 - makeActionButtonResponsive
>   2014-10-08 16:03:20.775 SmartTaxi[13009:60b] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[GMSUISettingsView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794 2014-10-08
>   16:03:20.779 SmartTaxi[13009:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout
>   still required after executing -layoutSubviews. GMSUISettingsView's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

the problem is that `GMSUISettingsView` is not calling `[super layoutSubviews]`..

I've seen this kind of error before.. the thing is that it happens with public classes such as `UITableViewCell`, as opposed to this private one `GMSUISettingsView` which is hidden in the guts of the google maps SDK for iOS. Had it been public.. i could have easily [swizzled](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) the method `layoutsubviews` inside of it using an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941256/766570) answer. But it's not a public method. How can I in runtime change the definition of it's `layoutsubviews` to get around this problem? (suggestions to accomplish the same goal using simpler methods are also welcome)

---

**UPDATE**

so based on feedback + a bit more research I did the following:

```
@interface AttackerClass : UIView @end
@implementation AttackerClass

- (void)_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews
{
    struct objc_super superTarget;
    superTarget.receiver = self;
    superTarget.super_class = class_getSuperclass(object_getClass(self));

    objc_msgSendSuper(&superTarget, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    NSLog(@":: calling send super")
    // PROBLEM: recursive call.. how do I call the *original* 
    // GMSUISettingsView implementation of layoutSubivews here?
    // replacing this with _autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews will
    // throw an error b/c GMSUISettingsView doesn't have that method defined
    objc_msgSend(self, @selector(layoutSubviews)); 
    objc_msgSendSuper(&superTarget, @selector(layoutSubviews));
}            
@end


Method attackerMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([AttackerClass class], @selector(_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews));
Method victimMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews));

method_exchangeImplementations(victimMethod, attackerMethod);
```

The problem with this approach is that anytime `GMSUISettingsView` calls `layoutSubviews`.. it is in effect calling `_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews`.. which then recursively calls `GMSUISettingsView` layoutsubviews.. so my app goes into an infinite recursive loop. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941256/766570) solved that problem by using a category.. but I can't in this case b/c `GMSUISettingsView` is a private class..

another way of asking the same question: how can i retain a reference to the unaltered version of `GMSUISettingsView's layoutSubviews` and use it in `_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews` so that I don't fall into this recursive call problem.

ideas?

Comment: That first piece of code is buggy.  It will always return *something* and that *something* won't always be a `UIButton` or `nil`, which is the intended semantic I would imagine.  Not to mention the uninitialized variable and the use of `isMemberOfClass` rather than `isKindOfClass`.

Comment: @Droppy for argument's sake.. let' assume it's not buggy and it reliably returns what i'm expecting

Comment: if all you need to do is send `layoutSubviews` to the objects `super` class, cant you do this with `objc_msgSendSuper` instead of swizzling?

Comment: @BradAllred tell me more? can you show me a code example of using `objc_msgSendSuper`?

Comment: that method doesn't seem to be available in the iOS runtime library.. only in osx runtime

Comment: yes it is. it is part of the objective-c runtime and this link clearly says ios in the url. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418

Comment: also se this SO answer which is also iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328915/call-super-without-super-keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this did it.. i'm not sure if this counts as an actual answer since i just got around the problem by simply calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]` instead of `[self layoutSubviews]`

```
void _autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    // calling super
    struct objc_super superTarget;
    superTarget.receiver = self;
    superTarget.super_class = class_getSuperclass(object_getClass(self));
    objc_msgSendSuper(&superTarget, @selector(layoutSubviews));

    // to get around calling layoutSubviews and having
    // a recursive call
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    objc_msgSendSuper(&superTarget, @selector(layoutSubviews));
}

- (void)replaceGMSUISettingsViewImplementation
{
    class_addMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews), (IMP)_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews, "v@:");

    Method existing = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews));
    Method new = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews));

    method_exchangeImplementations(existing, new);
}
```

Comment: Use `objc_msgSend` to send `@selector(_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews)` to `self`.  (Rather than calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]`.)  This has the effect of `[self _autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews]` which you already identified as the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

If you want to preserve original implementation you can get it and call it inside the blockImp. Then after that call [[aClass superclass] layoutSubviews] or call it with function pointer. Note that all this code need some error check and exception prevents.

```
//get method encoding
const char * encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews)));

void(^oldImplementation)(id aClass, SEL aSelector) = imp_getBlock(method_getImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews))));

id blockImp = ^void(id aClass, SEL aSelector)
{
    //old imlpementation
    oldImplementation(aClass, aSelector);

    //calling [super layoutSubviews]
    IMP aImp = [[aClass superclass] methodForSelector:@selector(layoutSubviews)];
    id (*func)(id, SEL) = (void *)aImp;
    func([aClass superclass], @selector(layoutSubviews));
};
IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(blockImp);
class_replaceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews), newImp, encoding);
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm sorry but I didn't fully understand do you want to completely override 'layoutsubviews' or to have original implementation and change just part of it. If it's the first you could use [class_replaceMethod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_replaceMethod) instead of swizzling. It will have performance hits though! Something like this should do the trick:

```
//get method encoding
const char * encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews)));

id blockImp = ^void(id aClass, SEL aSelector)
{
    //what you want to happen in layout subviews
};
IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(blockImp);
class_replaceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"GMSUISettingsView"), @selector(layoutSubviews), newImp, encoding);
```

I've not tested this on device/simulator but something like this should work for you. I assume you know it's not a really bright idea to manipulate private classes ;)

Comment: if it's not a bright idea to manipulate private classes then please suggest a better way of solving the problem i'm facing above without manipulating private classes

Comment: how do you ensure that `blockImp` still does what the original `layoutSubviews` does.. but also with adding [super layoutsubviews] as well?

Comment: aSelector above returns this `aSelector SEL "(\xae\xff\xbf/\xa1\xfa\x03 /4\x13\xe4\xfa\xa9\x01(" 0xbfffae08`.. so calling `oldImplementation(aClass, aSelector);` crashes..

Comment: hey take a look at my updated question.. now i'm stuck in a recursive call